# I'm trying to come up with an asymmetric sigmoid function where the degree of asymmetry can be controlled with a single parameter

Tags: functions

I've tried this:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(e^{-x}+1)^{\frac{1}{a}}}$$

Where $a$ is a parameter. However, the issue is that changing $a$ changes the value of $f(0)$, which is undesirable. I need some way to control the degree of asymmetry with only one parameter without changing the value of $f(0)$.

Comment: What do you mean by *degree of asymmetry*?

Comment: Why not just divide f by f(0)?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it in precise terms, so here's an image.
https://i.imgur.com/rpt9LND.png
The function on the right is more asymmetric, and I want to control how asymemtric is is with a parameter.

Comment: That looks awfully similar to the density function for the [Gumbel distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gumbel_distribution). [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a37znze1q5)'s a graph you can mess around with.